# How do I extract operators from a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, operators

I have two arrays, one of them has ints, and the other has chars of operators. So, suppose I have the following arrays: [12, 3] and ['+']. I want to transform this into the expression 12 + 3, which would be evaluated immediately (giving me 15). It should also preserve order of operations, so if I have [12, 3, 4] and ['+', '*'], it should give me 12 + 3 * 4, (that is, 24). I am guaranteed to have one fewer char than the number of ints, so there is always the correct number of operators. Is it possible to do this in C? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible in C. Have you tried any code?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [binary expression trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)

Comment: @ M M


How do I get an operator out of a char without using conditionals (as that would throw off order of operations)?

Comment: @blacktrance: Err, what?

Comment: @thejh: I know it's possible to use conditionals - if it's '+', take the first two elements of the array and add them, if it's '*', take the first two elements of the array and multiply them, and so on. But that doesn't preserve order of operations, because if I have an array that's like [1, 2, 3] and another array that's ['+', '*'], and I evaluate it using conditionals, I get (1+2)*3 when I want 1+(2*3).

Comment: @blacktrance: Ah, seems like my answer should help you. You have to scan for the operator with the highest priority, then work with its index.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible. Basic algorithm:

```
while there are operators left:
  // determine operation
  i = the index of the operator with the highest priority
  operator = operators[i]
  shift operators[i+1..end] one to the left (in other words, remove the operator from the array)
  operation_function = lookup operator

  // execute operation
  numbers[i] = operation_function(numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
  shift numbers[i+2..end] one to the left
```

Have fun turning that into C! :)

Comment: What does "operator with the highest priority" mean? For example, if I have the array ['+', '*', '*'], which of the multiplies has the higher priority? And if I do the multiplies first, does this solution preserve the addition symbol so it can be used at the end?

Comment: @blacktrance: For operators with the same priority, you want to handle those on the left-hand-side (smaller index) first. And yes, this preserves the addition until you've reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int calc(char op, int stack[], int *sp){
    switch(op){
    case '+':
        stack[*sp-1] += stack[*sp];
        --(*sp);
        return 1;
    case '-':
        stack[*sp-1] -= stack[*sp];
        --(*sp);
        return 1;
    case '*':
        stack[*sp-1] *= stack[*sp];
        --(*sp);
        return 1;
    case '/':
        stack[*sp-1] /= stack[*sp];
        --(*sp);
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int vals[] = {12, 3, 4}, vali=0, opi;
    char ops[] = {'+', '*', 0}, op_hold = 0;
    int stack[3], sp=-1;
    int result = 0;

    stack[++sp] = vals[vali++];
    for(opi=0;ops[opi];++opi){
        stack[++sp] = vals[vali++];
        if(ops[opi] == '+' || ops[opi] == '-'){
            if(ops[opi+1] == '*' || ops[opi+1] == '/'){
                op_hold = ops[opi];
            } else {
                calc(ops[opi], stack, &sp);
            }
        } else if(ops[opi] == '*' || ops[opi] == '/'){
            calc(ops[opi], stack, &sp);
            if(ops[opi+1] != '*' && ops[opi+1] != '/' && op_hold){
                calc(op_hold, stack, &sp);
                op_hold = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    result = stack[sp--];
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution; not a perfect one(integer division, etc), but it shows the algorithm.

It is very simple, just eliminates the operators from left to right and shift the arrays by one to the left after each elimination. '*' and '/' has higher precedence than '+' and '-'. The code is redundantand and solves only the burned-in input, breaking it into functions will be your job.

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nums[8]={1,5,8,2,5,3,4,7};
    int cnums = 8;
    char ops[7]={'+','-','/','*','+','-','*'};
    int cops=7;
    int flag =1;
    int i,j;

    while(flag)
    {
        flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<cnums;i++)
            if(ops[i]=='*' || ops[i]=='/')
            {
                if(ops[i]=='*')
                    nums[i]*=nums[i+1];
                else
                    nums[i]/=nums[i+1];
                flag=1;

                for(j=i;j<cops;j++)
                {
                    ops[j]=ops[j+1];
                    nums[j+1]=nums[j+2];
                }
                cnums--;
                cops--;
                break;
            }
    }

    flag=1;
    while(flag)
    {
        flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<cnums;i++)
            if(ops[i]=='+' || ops[i]=='-')
            {
                if(ops[i]=='+')
                    nums[i]+=nums[i+1];
                else
                    nums[i]-=nums[i+1];
                flag=1;

                for(j=i;j<cops;j++)
                {
                    ops[j]=ops[j+1];
                    nums[j+1]=nums[j+2];
                }
                cnums--;
                cops--;
                break;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can see it working on this [LINK](http://ideone.com/vyKCxN).

If you are familiar with formal languages, I recommend You to try [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) when You have a problem similar to this one.